# Can multiple AWS Data Pipelines share an EC2 resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-data-pipeline

I have 10 pipelines that run at least twice per hour each and use an EC2 resource to copy data from an external MySQL server to S3.

My preference is to let the pipelines launch their own resources (as opposed to use a long-running instance launched manually), but I don't want 10 EC2 instances running continuously (EC2 instances are billed per hour) just to perform a 1-minute job twice an hour. Is there a way to have the pipelines share a launched instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a long running EC2 instance combined with [Task runner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-using-task-runner.html).

> [...] In this pattern, you assume almost complete control over which
>   resources are used and how they are managed [...].

Also, EC2 instances are not billed per hour: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-per-second-billing-for-ec2-instances-and-ebs-volumes/

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware that I can use a long running EC2 instance. I was unaware of the billing change though.

Comment: Is there any other advantage to using a long running instance in this scenario? e.g., save time used to start up a new instance?

Comment: Managing the instance via the data pipeline is much simpler, I would not recommend using a long running instance.

Comment: How do you make sure the task runner stays running (automatic restart on failure etc) on the EC2?

Answer (score 0):

Not to be that guy lol but Google offers per minute charges (actually first 10 minutes are billed, then per minute)

Comment: That kind of change would require C-level approval, i.e. not an option :)